# How to prevent scroll when using drag and drop?

Tags: css, gwt, drag-and-drop, scroll

I've made a widget using gwt and I want to drag and drop objects inside a secondary panel.
This secondary panel is inside a smaller main panel.

Is there a way to prevent scrolling (shifting) the main panel when a widget is dragged inside the secondary panel using css?

Here is a link with I've tried so far. To simulate this effect drag a label to the right.
http://test4.vladm-ebas.appspot.com/TestComponent.html

If you drag them to far and drop them they will go right, else they will go back.

I'm using overflow: hidden because I only want the labels to be seen.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
overflow: visible;
```

in the parent (the one with the scrollbars)

Comment: I dont't want the secondary panel to be visible, I only want the part inside the main panel to be seen. Here is a link [link](http://test4.vladm-ebas.appspot.com/TestComponent.html). Scroll a label to the right to simulate the efect I'm talking about.

Comment: Sorry, but I think it's not possible.